# Make objects in an array unique depending on multiple subkeys

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I found this example on

https://blog.adriaan.io/make-array-with-objects-unique-on-multiple-keys-in-javascript.html

```
const browsers = [ 
    { os: "OS X", 
        os_version: "Catalina", 
        browser: "chrome", 
        browser_version: "30.0" 
    }, 
    { 
        os: "Windows", 
        os_version: "7", 
        browser: "chrome", 
        browser_version: "40.0" 
    }, 
    { 
        os: "Windows", 
        os_version: "7", 
        browser: "chrome", 
        browser_version: "50.0" 
    } 
]; 


const makeUnique = (array = [], keys = []) => { 
    if (!keys.length || !array.length) return []; 
    
    return array.reduce((list, item) => { 
        const hasItem = list.find(listItem => keys.every(key => listItem[key] === item[key]) ); 
        if (!hasItem) list.push(item); 
        return list; 
    },[]); 
}; 


console.log(makeUnique(browsers, ["os", "os_version"]));
```

I would like to use this with my objectarray but i use keys in a key. Does anyone know how to adapt the method to my example in order to ignore double bounds?

```
const tiles = [
    {
        name: "pattern1",
        type: "jpg",
        size: 1024,
        bounds:{topleft_x: 45, topleft_y: 45, downright_x: -45, downright_y: -45},
    },
        name: "pattern2",
        type: "jpg",
        size: 1024,
        bounds:{topleft_x: 90, topleft_y: 90, downright_x: 45, downright_y: 45},
    },
        name: "pattern3",
        type: "jpg",
        size: 1024,
        bounds:{topleft_x: 45, topleft_y: 45, downright_x: -45, downright_y: -45},
    },
    //...
];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need a traverse function this function gets an object and a string called path, path is something like `bounds.topleft_y`

```
function traverse(obj, path) {
    if (!path.includes('.')) return obj[path];
    return path.split('.').reduce((a, k) => a[k], obj)
}
```

and you need to change makeUnique function

```
const makeUnique = (array = [], keys = []) => {
    if (!keys.length || !array.length) return []; 

    return array.reduce((list, item) => {
        const hasItem = list.find(listItem => keys.every(key => traverse(listItem, key) === traverse(item, key)));
        console.log(data, item, hasItem)
        if (!hasItem) list.push(item);
        return list;
    }, [])
}
```

and here is how you can use it

```
makeUnique(data, ['type', 'bounds.topleft_y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `dedupe(arr,keys,last)` returns an array containing the de-duped entries from `arr` where the array `keys` defines the properties of each element of `arr` that will be part of the comparison. The comparison will look at simple values as such but in the case of objects (like the objects behind the property `bounds`) all *their* properties will also have to be unique.

If the (optional) third argument `last` has a truthy value then the last of the encountered "same" elements will be returned, otherwise it is the first one.

```js
const tiles = [
{
    name: "pattern1",
    type: "jpg",
    size: 1024,
    bounds:{topleft_x: 45, topleft_y: 45, downright_x: -45, downright_y: -45},
},{
    name: "pattern2",
    type: "jpg",
    size: 1024,
    bounds:{topleft_x: 90, topleft_y: 90, downright_x: 45, downright_y: 45},
},{
    name: "pattern3",
    type: "jpg",
    size: 1024,
    bounds:{topleft_x: 45, topleft_y: 45, downright_x: -45, downright_y: -45},
}
];

function dedupe(arr,keys,last){
 const coll={};
 const flt=keys.reduce((a,k)=>{
  a[k]=(typeof arr[0][k] == "object")?Object.keys(arr[0][k]):1;
  return a
 },{});
 
 arr.forEach(el=>
  (coll[Object.entries(flt).map(([k,sk])=>
   (sk==1&&el[k]||sk.map(kk=>el[k][kk]).join("|"))??"").join("|")]??=[]).push(el)
 );
 return Object.values(coll).map(el=>el.at(last?-1:0));
}

const resFirst=dedupe(tiles,["type","bounds"]); // pattern1, pattern2
console.log(resFirst);
const resLast=dedupe(tiles,["type","bounds"],1); // pattern3, pattern2
console.log(resLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to refactor your `makeUnique` function to accept a comparator function instead of a list of keys. This will make the function general enough to be used on arrays containing a range of element types from primitives to nested objects as in your question.

Here is an example that refactors the `reduce()` call of your current function into a `for...of` loop which lends a little more clarity to the logic. It also declares a helper function `resultHasDuplicate()` outside of the loop which accepts an object and compares it against each element of the result array within a `some()` call which uses our passed comparator function to determine duplication.

```js
function makeUnique(array, isDuplicate) {
  const result = [];

  const resultHasDuplicate = (candidateElement) =>
    result.some((resultElement) =>
      isDuplicate(resultElement, candidateElement)
    );

  for (const item of array) {
    if (!resultHasDuplicate(item)) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

/**
 * All keys of nested object used to de-dupe
 */
const titles = [{ name: 'pattern1', type: 'jpg', size: 1024, bounds: { topleft_x: 45, topleft_y: 45, downright_x: -45, downright_y: -45, }, }, { name: 'pattern2', type: 'jpg', size: 1024, bounds: { topleft_x: 90, topleft_y: 90, downright_x: 45, downright_y: 45 }, }, { name: 'pattern3', type: 'jpg', size: 1024, bounds: { topleft_x: 45, topleft_y: 45, downright_x: -45, downright_y: -45, }, },];

const uniqueTitles = makeUnique(titles, (result, candidate) =>
  Object.entries(result.bounds).every(
    ([key, value]) => candidate.bounds[key] === value
  )
);

console.log(uniqueTitles);

/**
 * Simple strict equality used to de-dupe array of numbers
 */
const numbers = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5];
const uniqueNumbers = makeUnique(numbers, (a, b) => a === b);

console.log(uniqueNumbers);

/**
 * Original 'browsers' example using a curried helper function
 */
const browsers = [{ os: 'OS X', os_version: 'Catalina', browser: 'chrome', browser_version: '30.0', }, { os: 'Windows', os_version: '7', browser: 'chrome', browser_version: '40.0', }, { os: 'Windows', os_version: '7', browser: 'chrome', browser_version: '50.0', },];

// Helper function using currying to return comparator function
const hasDuplicateProperties = (keys) => (a, b) =>
    keys.every((key) => a[key] === b[key]);

const uniqueBrowsers = makeUnique(
    browsers,
    hasDuplicateProperties(['os', 'os_version'])
);

console.log(uniqueBrowsers);
```

---

Alternative as a `filter()` call using a closure to track seen elements

```js
const titles = [{ name: 'pattern1', type: 'jpg', size: 1024, bounds: { topleft_x: 45, topleft_y: 45, downright_x: -45, downright_y: -45, }, }, { name: 'pattern2', type: 'jpg', size: 1024, bounds: { topleft_x: 90, topleft_y: 90, downright_x: 45, downright_y: 45 }, }, { name: 'pattern3', type: 'jpg', size: 1024, bounds: { topleft_x: 45, topleft_y: 45, downright_x: -45, downright_y: -45, }, },];

const uniqueTitles = ((seen) =>
  titles.filter(
    (candidateElement) =>
      !seen.some((seenElement) =>
        Object.entries(seenElement.bounds).every(
          ([key, value]) => candidateElement.bounds[key] === value
        )
      ) && seen.push(candidateElement)
  ))([]);

console.log(uniqueTitles);
```

Answer (score -1):

The crux of any deduping algorithm is how equality is determined. In the example algorithm you provided, that occurs with checking `listItem[key] === item[key]`. Strict equality (===) works great for comparing primitive values, but there is no built-in way to compare objects (like `bounds`). Therefore, you have to use a custom value equality function.

There is a great npm package called [`value-equal`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/value-equal) that does this for you. You can also view its implementation [here](https://github.com/mjackson/value-equal/blob/master/modules/index.js).

Once you have a `valueEqual()` function, you can swap it into the algorithm like so:

```js
const makeUnique = (array = [], keys = []) => { 
    if (!keys.length || !array.length) return []; 
    
    return array.reduce((list, item) => { 
        const hasItem = list.find(listItem => keys.every(key => valueEqual(listItem[key], item[key]))); 
        if (!hasItem) list.push(item); 
        return list; 
    },[]); 
};
```

Then you can invoke the algorithm as before:

```js
console.log(makeUnique(tiles, ["type", "bounds"]));
```